# Console browser for Centos 8

Tags: console, browser, lynx

What console browser work under Centos 8?
I tried to install them all but

```
sudo yum -y install lynx w3m links  elinks links2 netrik

No match for argument: lynx
No match for argument: w3m
No match for argument: links
No match for argument: elinks
No match for argument: links2
No match for argument: netrik
Error: Unable to find a match
```

Comment: It seems they are not available (Your command gives the same results for me and `yum search` with the individual entries does not output anything interesting either). Hence, it would seem that it is necessary to go for third-party repositories or compile your favourite console browser from source.

Comment: fwiw, EPEL supposedly provides the packages from Fedora, but it appears to have only about a quarter of those.  The [Fedora package](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=lynx(x86-64)) might work (with the caveat that using Centos/Redhat-Enterprise puts you back in time a year or two on library dependencies).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selected answer no longer works as of Feb 2021.  Apparently, the "PowerTools" or "powertools" name is trademarked and contested.

To install lynx on RHEL8, you can use:

```
# sudo subscription-manager repos --enable codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms
```

Then

```
# sudo yum install lynx
```

Yields

```
# lynx -version
Lynx Version 2.8.9rel.1 (08 Jul 2018)
```

Comment: Lynx version 2.8.7 supported on centos8?

Comment: This also works for elinks!

Comment: `sudo subscription-manager repos --enable codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms` doesn't work for me. I use CentOS 8 Streams.

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=powertools install elinks
```

*The command is case-sensitive as specified by @Hasanuzzaman Sattar (--enablerepo=Powertools won't work)*

Comment: Welcome, Already posted as answer.

Comment: `sudo yum --enablerepo=powertools install elinks`, this command is case sensitive

Answer (score 3):

At least `elinks`, `links` and `lynx` can be installed when PowerTools repository is enabled.